# DIY video file streaming from linux/osx to iOS devices

Tags: ios, macos, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

This is for a hobby project. I want to learn about video streaming and also create something that's useful for me as well.

The project should be able to run a server on my macbook and a client on my iPad that will allow me to watch the videos I've got stored on my laptop without having to copy them in my iPad over my wifi.

I know there are solutions like Plex, Air Video etc. that allow me to do it. But since my goal is to practice writing some client/server code, I want to create something myself with the basic functionality of these apps.

I figured I'd probably need something like ffmpeg and Apple's HTTP Live Streaming (HLS), but I don't have a Apple developer account to be able to use it. I do have Xcode in my mac. So, some free 3rd party library for HLS or something equivalent. I also fond this tool called https://www.bento4.com.

How would I go about getting started with such an application and what are the libraries I could use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to go between your MAC and a local client on the same network/WiFi, then you can simply set up a HTTP server to serve static files on our MAC, and connect to the server from the browser in your device.

This will most probably work fine with a local network connection as you are suggesting.

You can make it a bit more challenging by creating an App to query the server, list the videos there and then allow them playback in the app.

If you want to add adaptive bit rate streaming (protocols like HLS and MPEG-DASH) then this gets considerably more complex. The simplest approach, and possibly the best way to learn the domain, would be to build on an open source streaming sever like GStreamer (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org).